# How to embed ArcGIS Server Map in personal Google or Blogger website?

Tags: arcgis-server, google

I have created my own free Google website, and I want to embed a web map on it that I have created with ArcGIS Server.

Can I do this, and if so, how?

Comment: Out of luck on that option, Amazon EC2 will host ArcGIS Server, you could iframe the amazon instance to the google site. http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgisserver/10.0/arcgis-server-amazon

Comment: @Mapperz, an ArcGIS server instance costs lots of money. That is a bad solution! See my solution below. If you want to set up your own web-mapping server, use GeoServer. That is a massive overhead for what OP wants to do, though, which is embed a map that he already has somewhere!

Comment: Alex the user has ArcGIS server having it available on EC2 is scaleable if required/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you mean ArcGIS Server, then you probably mean that you shared a layer. IF so, then you need to get a html page up that displays that layer, then you can embed that using an iframe in another page.

If you mean ArcGIS Online, then see below.

If you add the code below to a page that supports iframe then you will embed my map in your page.

For you to do that, set up your map in ArcGIS Online, then click the 'share' button, make it public, then click the 'embed this map' button. It's that simple.

```
<iframe width="500" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/embedViewer.html?webmap=96e14d904c8a4b81a9c04c00b06264a5&amp;extent=89.0225,-58.2912,180,-1.1078"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=96e14d904c8a4b81a9c04c00b06264a5&amp;extent=89.0225,-58.2912,180,-1.1078" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left" target="_blank">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you merely want to host the html & javascript, then you have a lot options.  The simplest may be to use a dropbox account or a service like this makes it very easy: http://www.site44.com/